# Passing variables to Python script from Batch File error

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file that, runs two python scripts and assigns to variables the values returned from those scripts. After that, it sends those variables to a python script.

Batch File:

```
SET VAR_NAME=Issues
SET VAR_OUTCOME=Done
cd C:\Users\ABREUH\PycharmProjects\Jira
python -c "import extract_control_details;extract_control_details.details_date()" > Output
python -c "import extract_control_details;extract_control_details.details_id()" > Output2
SET /p VAR_DATE=<Output
SET /p VAR_ID=<Output2
DEL Output
DEL Output2
python -c "import extract_control_details;extract_control_details.rows_processed()" > Output4
SET /p VAR_ROW=<Output4
DEL Output4
IF %VAR_OUTCOME%==Done (python -c "import 
extract_control_details;extract_control_details.nothing("%VAR_NAME%", "%VAR_DATE%", "%VAR_ROW%", "%VAR_ID%")")
```

This is where i get the following error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
import extract_control_details;extract_control_details.nothing(Issues CACBNBCNCEMBFKAIKFBLBAH 564 31323)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think this code produced this error

Comment: I'm going to assume that your batch file's penultimate line does not end with `"import`. Can you please copy exactly the content and formatting of your batch file content, or confirm that what you have currently for its content and formatting is correct.

Comment: This is some of the more convoluted code I've seen in a while.   Most of the complexity is passing data between batch and python layers.   Just so the whole thing in python so you don't have to keep interpolating values between batch and python.

Comment: What about just using one output file, overwriting it for each of those commands, then you'd have only one to delete. Also I'd ask, instead of outputting three different pieces of information, from running essentially the same command on three occasions, would it not be possible to grab the Date, Id, and Row count from a single command?

Comment: I guess so.. My main purpose with this is to get those variables into a function in python but i get that error where it points to the second variable date.. Before it was "2021-07-04 18:00:00.000" and i got that error. I thought it was because of the dash so i changed everything in the date string to letters so that in the final function it would convert back. But still errors with that variable

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing your solution much more difficult by using a batch file.
Why not to do:

```py
import extract_control_details
NAME = "Issues"
DATE = extract_control_details.details_date()
ID = extract_control_details.details_id()
ROW = extract_control_details.rows_processed()
OUTCOME = extract_control_details.nothing(NAME, DATE, ROW, ID)
print(OUTCOME)
```

It's the same that you are trying to do, but implemented on a python script

Comment: I guess i can make it all on python, just wondered if it was possible with a batch to run it. Running functions and getting the values back so that, in the final function it inserts data based on prior values. After that running that batch file from the task scheduler

Comment: Have in account that if a function returns a date, bash will receive it as a string. That could be related to the error you mentioned in your other comment